# Mysql query execution via ssh

Tags: mysql, ssh

I want to make bash alias to run mysql query via ssh

```
ssh vagrant@192.168.10.10  "mysql wp-theme -e 'DELETE * FROM wp_options where option_name like \'%_transient%\''";
```

but problem is with part `\'%_transient%\'` where i tried to escape `'`

I got error

```
bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Comment: Can you try changing the \ to \\ as I think I saw something about these being interpreted twice (once for shell and once for SQL).

Comment: Hmm i still got same errors with `ssh vagrant@192.168.10.10  "mysql wp-theme -e 'SELECT * FROM wp_options where option_name like \\'%_transient%\\';'"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a while I found the solution

```
ssh vagrant@192.168.10.10  "mysql wp-theme -e 'DELETE FROM \`wp_options\` where \`option_name\` like \"%_transient%\";'"
```